# Comment in aspell .dic files?

Tags: dictionary, comments, aspell

They look like this:

```
abaft
abbreviation/M
abdicate/DNGSn
Abelard/M
abider/M
Abidjan
ablaze
abloom
```

I am using this kind of dictionary with Node.js application, but I will need it to be smarter. Specifically, I want to remember occurrence probability of every word based on already processed text. I'd like to save this information in existing `.dic` file - but how to do that without making it invalid?

Is there any comment syntax that would allow me to store additional data next to the words in file? Such that normal dictionary parser will ignore it?